# Grouping array of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was looking for group by functionality over array of array and wrote something like,

```
var response = {
  "data": {
    "results": {
      "facebook": [
        [
          "Campaign Name",
          'promo',
          'id'
        ],
        [
          "Sok_MPA_10Link_IntOnlineShoppingSites_1412",
          "promo1",
          4
        ],
        [
          "PPLA",
          "promo1",
          9
        ],
        [
          "PPLA",
          "promo2",
          90
        ],
        [
          "Sok_MPA_10Link_IntOnlineShoppingSites_1412",
          "promo1",
          45,
          5
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "exception": null,
  "status": "OK",
  "sokratiRequestId": null,
  "json": null
};


var mapData = {};

$.map(response.data.results, function(value, key) {
  headers = value.shift();

  $.map(response.data.results[key], function(data) {
    $.each(headers, function(index, column) {
      if (index == headers.indexOf('id')) return true;

      if (mapData[column] == undefined) {
        mapData[column] = {};
      }
      if (mapData[column][data[index]] == undefined) {
        mapData[column][data[index]] = 0;
      }
      mapData[column][data[index]] += data[headers.indexOf('id')]
    });
  });
  console.log(mapData)
});
```

Basically I want to group over multiple fields in the array - Like ["Campaign Name" & promo']

Any good way to achieve it?

Output should be -

```
"Campaign Name": {
    PPLA: 99
    Sok_MPA_10Link_IntOnlineShoppingSites_1412: 49
},
"promo": {
    promo1: 58
    promo2: 90
}
```

### https://jsfiddle.net/ezg8Lzdr/

### Note

Answer should purely be in JS - No other frameworks [No lodash]

Comment: How should your output look like ?

Comment: @RayonDabre check edit

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

With [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and an object for the result. The given `groups` items are taken either for the group property and their index for the wanted data part to get a sub property.

```js
var response = { "data": { "results": { "facebook": [["Campaign Name", 'promo', 'id'], ["Sok_MPA_10Link_IntOnlineShoppingSites_1412", "promo1", 4], ["PPLA", "promo1", 9], ["PPLA", "promo2", 90], ["Sok_MPA_10Link_IntOnlineShoppingSites_1412", "promo1", 45, 5]] } }, "exception": null, "status": "OK", "sokratiRequestId": null, "json": null },
    data = response.data.results.facebook,
    result = {},
    groups = data.shift();

groups.pop();

result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    groups.forEach(function (b, i) {
        r[b] = r[b] || {};
        r[b][a[i]] = (r[b][a[i]] || 0) + a[2];
    });
    return r;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I failed to explain I guess... I want to group values over two indexes of array. Not sorting

Comment: I have updated question .. Please let me know if you want any more info

Comment: I think I did it the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101590/discussion-between-pilot-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small function on JS that might help you:

```
function groupBy(collection, property) {

var i = 0, val, index,
    values = [], result = [];
for (; i < collection.length; i++) {
    val = collection[i][property];
    index = values.indexOf(val);
    if (index > -1)
        result[index].push(collection[i]);
    else {
        values.push(val);
        result.push([collection[i]]);
    }
}
return result;
```

};

The use is simple:

```
groupBy(myArray, "facebook");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data schema is pretty much fixed:

```js
var response = {
  "data": {
    "results": {
      "facebook": [
        [
          "Campaign Name",
          'promo',
          'id'
        ],
        [
          "Sok_MPA_10Link_IntOnlineShoppingSites_1412",
          "promo1",
          4
        ],
        [
          "PPLA",
          "promo1",
          9
        ],
        [
          "PPLA",
          "promo2",
          90
        ],
        [
          "Sok_MPA_10Link_IntOnlineShoppingSites_1412",
          "promo1",
          45,
          5
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "exception": null,
  "status": "OK",
  "sokratiRequestId": null,
  "json": null
};

var face = response.data.results.facebook;

//remove first row which is a schema
face.shift();

//take in index of column, return grouped sum
var reduce = function(index) {
  return face.reduce((t, a) => {
    t[a[index]] = (t[a[index]] || 0) + a[2];
    return t;
  }, {});
}

//final result
var result = {
  "Campaign Name": reduce(0),
  "promo": reduce(1)
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score -1):

For such basic operations on arrays, collection or whatever in JavaScript, I would recommend to use frameworks like **lodash** which is full of tricks like this one you will need everywhere in your project:

https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy

Answer (score -1):

The most common way is to use library to data manipulation like https://lodash.com/

Using this library you can group your data like this:

```
var result = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy("color")
    .pairs()
    .map(function(currentItem) {
        return _.object(_.zip(["color", "users"], currentItem));
    })
    .value();
```